# mysql sum only specific groups of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to sum only specific groups of a table?  for example if I have

```
KEYS  /  VALS
A     /   1
A     /   2
B     /   3
B     /   3 
C     /   1
C     /   1
```

and I want to get by grouping only A and C but not any others such as B above:

```
KEYS  /  VALS
A     /   3
B     /   3
B     /   3 
C     /   2
```

This seems straightforward with a stored proc but I am not sure if it is possible with a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION ALL` the non-B part with the B part:

```
select keys, sum(vals)
from tablename
where keys <> 'B'
group by keys
union all
select keys, vals
from tablename
where keys = 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to achieve this outcome using a union because any group by will apply to the entire resultset. With union you can combine 2 independent queries, therefore the group by will only apply to 1 of the queries:

```
select keys, sum(vals) as vals
    from yourtable
    where keys in ('A','B')
    group by keys
union
select keys, vals
    from yourtable
    where keys not in ('A','B')
```

Comment: UNION ALL, to get both (B, 3) rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below queries

```
SELECT keys, SUM(vals) as vals
FROM yourtable
WHERE keys in ('A','C')
GROUP BY keys
```

Comment: this does not work, you need the union all as indicated in other answers.  the will leave out the B rows